# Code Signing with Hardware Token (EV Certificate) mixing jarsigner, signtool and codesign in batch

Tags: token, build-automation, code-signing

We have currently a fully automated process to generate installers from source code using `ANT`.

We create different files of below type :

1. JAR
2. EXE
3. DLL
4. MSI
5. APP files for the MAC OS X version.

Each one of the files is digitally signed, but the digital certificate is stored in the required format of each tool.

For example: jarsigner uses JSR files. signtool uses the digital certificates repository in the control panel and codesign uses the similar repository in the MAC. We created a PKCS12 to import our certificate on every other required container.

Now we plan to shift up and use an EV certificate for code signing that is stored in a hardware token connected via USB to the computer. The challenge is to integrate the hardware token with all signing tools from different vendors and use it in a batch mode so we don't need to type a password for every file to be signed (we can sign up to 2,000 files in one batch).

I am searching for a solution that shows it can handle all requirements. I've found no solution yet.

Comment: I think mean to say that jarsigner uses *JKS* files. In addition now days it often also supports PKCS#12 keystores.

Comment: jarsigner supports integration with external libraries, one of them supports PKCS11. Hardware Tokens supports PKCS11 as well. We finally managed to obtain a working solution but it was really a pain

Answer (score 0):

SignServer Enterprise [[1](https://www.primekey.se/technologies/products-overview/signserver-enterprise/)] is a server-side software based on SignServer [[2](https://www.signserver.org/)] that currently at least supports the formats in points 1-3 and using hardware tokens.

This makes the signing process the same regardless of signature type/format.

Unfortunately, not yet points 4 and 5 all though MSI support might be coming soon.

Comment: SignServer now also supports signing MSI files.